# Separate text of an element in xslt (from xml)

Tags: html, xml, xslt, dtd

xml

```
<product>
  <name>Smartphone Samsung S6</name>
</product>
<product>
  <name>Smartphone Samsung S8</name>
</product>
```

html

```
<h1>Smartphone<small>Samsung S6</small></h1>
<h1>Smartphone<small>Samsung S8</small></h1>
```

How do I do that in xslt? output: html

```
<xsl:for-each select="product">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Well, what are the criteria for marking up that text within a `small` element, is that the word `Samsung` followed by another word or anything behing `Smartphone`? Which version of XSLT do you use?

Comment: Samsung is followed by S6 or S8. Nothing before Smartphone. xsl 2.0

Comment: Are your product names always going to have the same format of "Category Make Model"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="product">
    <h1>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="name" regex="^(Smartphone) (Samsung S[0-9])">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                <small>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                </small>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </h1>
</xsl:for-each>
```

See Transformation on http://xsltransform.net/jxN8NpA

Comment: And if I have another product named Laptop HP 647j? I couldnt do that

Comment: change `^(Smartphone) (Samsung S[0-9])` to `^(Smartphone|Laptop) (Samsung S[0-9]|HP [0-9]+[a-z]?)`

Comment: Check this transformation [http://xsltransform.net/jxN8NpA](http://xsltransform.net/jxN8NpA)